# julia: create and use a local package without Internet

Tags: package, julia

I am trying to create a package of the julia language and use it in a project.
For now I have only a jl file, I dont know how to create a package with it.

I have read this [link](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/packages/) but I still dont know how to do it. I want to create a local package with a jl file and use it in my own local project with this code: `using MyPackage`.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should put the file in

~/.julia/v0.X/MyPackage/src/MyPackage.jl

Where ~ is your home directory and X is the version number of Julia that you are using. X will be 3, unless you are on the development or nightly version of Julia, in which case it will be 4.

Also note that for this to work the file MyPackage.jl should define the module MyPackage and export the definitions you want to have available after calling using MyPackage.

To automate the creation of this structure to you can call Pkg.generate("MyPackage", "MIT"), where MIT can be replaced by another supported default licence. This will create the folder in the correct place and set up the module structure for you. Then you just need to incorporate your code into that structure.

---

### EDIT

Here is an example of two possible contents for the file `~/.julia/v0.3/MyPackage/src/MyPackage.jl`:

```
module MyPackage

function test()
    1
end

end  # module
```

and

```
module MyPackage

export test

function test()
    1
end

end  # module
```

In the first case I have not `export`ed anything. Thus, when calling `using MyPackage` only the module `MyPackage` itself would be made available to the user. If I wanted to use the `test` function, I would have to use the fully qualified name: `MyPackage.test()`.

In the second case I chose to export the function `test`. This happened on the line `export test`. Now when I call `using MyPackage`, both the module `MyPackage` and the function `test` are available to the user. I do not need to use a fully qualified name to access `test` anymore: `test()` will work.

Comment: I tried like this: Pkg.generate("MyPackage","MIT"); After this I found there was a directory name MyPackage in the path ~/.julia/v0.3/MyPackage  and in this directory, there is a directory name src. Here I found a file named MyPackage.jl. So I edit this file and save. But still, I cant use it.

Comment: I typed this: Pkg.status() and I found that MyPackage is "0.0.0- master (unregistered, dirty)"

Comment: What happens when, in a fresh Julia session, you execute using MyPackage?

Comment: yes. I finished creating and now I want to use it by "using MyPackage". I think the problem is MyPackage is dirty.

Comment: No, dirty means you have uncommitted (in the git sense) changes in the package directory (repository). This is not a problem. Do you get an error when you run using MyPackage, or are your functions just not being made available. If it is the latter, I suspect that you have forgotten to export then from within the module inside MyPackage.jl

Comment: In fact I am a c++ programmer. My colleague works on the julia. Now I am trying to embed the julia into my c++ project. So I am just trying a very simple package to make sure that I can embed my colleague's julia package. So in the MyPackage.jl, I just write a function like this: function test() return 1 end

Comment: I have succeeded in embedding an official julia package such as "Distributions". with the code "using DIstributions", I can use its functions such as Normal(). Now I want to embed a local package but I dont know how. This is why I pose this question.

Comment: Could you explain "you have forgotten to export then from within the module inside MyPackage.jl"?

Comment: u see I have generated the whole but empty package. It's empty because the file /src/MyPackage.jl is empty. In my opinion, I should add some function into this file, right? And I dont need to change /test/runtests.jl, right? For now, I type "function test() return 1 end" into /src/MyPackage.jl and try to use this function but I cant.

Comment: Excellent. Enjoy Julia!